# A question I submitted as a guest was removed. How can I recover the question, and why was it removed without any feedback?

Tags: discussion, deleted-posts, unregistered-users

I submitted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1636119/how-can-i-manage-a-company-facebook-page-as-an-employee-without-providing-phot) as a guest, while logged out.

For reasons unknown the post was removed. Perhaps it was deemed unsuitable for Superuser or whatever, but in any case I would like to recover the text of the question so I can edit it and/or post it elsewhere.

Additionally I think it is extremely poor that a question would be removed without leaving even a trace and without providing feedback to the author. Really, *really* frustrating.

Comment: Looks like closed as off topic. Deletion was by community which is a little odd. That said there's no real way to contact a anonymous user.

Comment: I voted to close this as site-specific because your question would be much more sufficiently answered by the moderators, or high rep users, of Super User over on [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/). I did not downvote, as I do believe your concerns are completely legitimate, but I do still feel this is much better suited for the per-site meta in this case.

Comment: @WackGet In general, people don't comment about their close reasons, particularly when the close reason they are using is one where the question directly and clearly fits a stock close reason for the site, and it's an *inherent, unresolvable issue* with the question (i.e. you *can't* edit this to be on-topic and have it be the same question). While I understand it's frustrating to see close votes, you have enough experience on the Stack Exchange Network such that you couldd have made a reasonable assumption as to why it might be close-voted by looking at the reasons in the close-flag dialog.

Comment: However, I'd agree that the [on-topic page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) should be edited to at least explicitly state the most common off-topic reasons, or *at least* that questions which are specific to a single site should be raised on that site's Meta, not here.

Comment: @Makyen I've [filed a feature request for that here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326754/the-help-center-and-sidebar-on-meta-dont-indicate-that-site-specific-questions)

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Because the on-topic page is something which can be edited by moderators, isn't something which needs intervention from SE, and the requested change isn't a change in policy, I just raised a custom flag with the request shortly after writing that comment.

Comment: “Additionally I think it is extremely poor that a question would be removed without leaving even a trace and without providing feedback to the author. Really, really frustrating.” - It’s really really frustrating to have to filter out out of scope questions where they are explicitly out of scope on a community.  Facebook questions are explicitly called out as being out of scope on Super User, the tag explicitly indicates this fact, yet this guidance was ignored.  Had you asked it while you were logged in you could see the close reason.

Answer (score 7):

By following the first link from the [question link that you provided](https://superuser.com/questions/1636119/how-can-i-manage-a-company-facebook-page-as-an-employee-without-providing-phot) I reached [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-questions).

That gives multiple reasons why your question may have been deleted.

If you think that none of them apply then I think you should post to the Meta of the site that your question was deleted from to see if there was another reason for it to have happened.